# Update quantity "virtual_available" from odoo to magento with scheduled actions?

Tags: magento, odoo, magento-1.9, odoo-8

how can I update "virtual_available" as well as the quantity available with the scheduled actions from Odoo to Magento?

I would like to be able to link the Odoo variable "virtual_available" with my custom Magento attribute "qty_virtual".

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?